# get task name of celery AsyncResult

Tags: python, celery

I am using celery to execute my asynchronous tasks and what i'm trying to achieve is get the name and the id of each task in the work flow after i executed it.

```
        exec_workflow = chain(
            task1.si(),
            task2.si(),
            task3.si()
    )

    result = exec_workflow.apply_async()

    tasks = []
    for t in result._parents():
        tasks.append({"id": t.id, "name": t.name})
```

but it seems like AsyncResult does not have the name property for some strange reason. any idea on what would be the appropriate way to do this?

A different approach to this maybe to force an id on each task before i execute apply_async and this would solve my problem cause i will be able to match id to task name. but i'm not sure if its possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score -11, accepted):

Alright so I've solved my problem. What i did eventually was to just set the id property of each task.

Comment: Can you provide an example for this?

Comment: Downvoted due to lack of answer. Stackoverflow is a QA resource and a useless answer won't help anyone

Answer (score 2):

Not the best solution but it works.

```
result = signature.apply_async()
result._cache['task_name']
#'procedures.tasks.stop'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration option `result_extended` in Celery for this purpose (it is set to `False` by default).

> Enables extended task result attributes (name, args, kwargs, worker, retries, queue, delivery_info) to be written to backend.

Ref.:
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/configuration.html#result-extended

#### Consumer example (Worker)

```py
from typing import Final

from celery import Celery

app: Final = Celery(
    broker="amqp://...",
    result_backend="redis://...",
    result_extended=True,
)

@app.task(
    name="foo-service:bar"
)
def _() -> int:
    return 42
```

#### Producer example (Client)

```py
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Final

from celery import Celery
from celery.result import AsyncResult

app: Final = Celery(broker="amqp://...", result_backend="redis://...")

result: AsyncResult = app.send_task("foo-service:bar")
assert result.get() == 42
assert result.name == "foo-service:bar"
assert result.queue == ...
assert result.args == ...
assert result.kwargs == ...
assert result.worker == ...
pprint(result.__dict__)
```